# List of all built in symbols in z3

Tags: z3

I'm using the smt2-lib interface of z3 and trying to define the following:

```
(declare-const rem (set sl$REQ))
```

And get this error:

```
(error "line 36 column 31: invalid declaration, builtin symbol rem")
```

Is there a way to get a complete list of all the predefined symbols so that I can do an automatic renaming?

Thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's not quite that trivial. Depending on options and logic definitions, the list of pre-defined symbols may change. But, you can get a list of all potentially predefined symbols by grepping for `builtin_name` in `src/ast/*_decl_plugin.cpp`. For example, the `rem` symbol is defined at [arith_decl_plugin.cpp:540](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/arith_decl_plugin.cpp#L540).